# 'Edge detection' with Nodes or bpy

Tags: shaders, geometry-nodes

I know this must be possible because Blender can take this image...
[image]

And by selecting the object the edges can be found perfectly.

[image]

So surely this most be a capability of Blender?  I've already tried Bevel and pointedness, and I wasn't able to get the desired effect.  Any ideas?

Comment: Are you trying to use this edge detection in some kind of modeling application or in a shader tree?

Comment: [bmesh](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.types.html) maintains boundary loop information internally that you can use find the boundary edge loops; but that information is not available to the material subsystem.

Comment: There is the line art capability of Blender.  Suggestion. Please search Freestyle.  Typically on the bottom of the Render Properties panel.

Comment: @atomicbezierslinger I am familiar, but it is less accurate than whatever algorithm the object select edge detection is using.  It is also a bit tricky to bend to my will.

Comment: @Jakemoyo It would be cool to get it for modeling application, but a Shader tree would be great.  Bevel and pointedness are not working on this petal geometry for some reason

Comment: @MartyFouts can I programatically create a spline derived from this geometry and then extrude the curve, then apply an emission?

Comment: bmesh only works on meshes, so if your flower is a curve, you'd have to convert it to a mesh but sure you could do that.  In bmesh terms each pedal would be an island, so iterate over islands, find the boundary loops, extrude those on normals, and assign the new faces to a material slot that has your emission material.  It's a lot of code, but you can find it in answers to various questions here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got something i think might work, totally procedural. Using Geometry Nodes. I kind of over emphasized the edge thickness for visibility in this demo, but its easily adjustable by setting the changing the EdgeScale value to slightly something slightly larger.

It's not totally perfect but for a proof of concept I think it works alright.

[image]

Node setup:

[image]

Comment: Good enough for now, thanks Jakemoyo